# Finding absolute extrema and critical numbers

Tags: calculus

The function **f(x)=sin(x)+cos(x)** is focused on the interval [0,π/2]. Find the absolute extrema.

I took the derivative **dy/dx=cos(x)-sin(x)** and set it to 0. When I graphed it I found one critical point to be π/4. Is there another way of finding this critical point not just by observing the graph? I'm not sure what algebra I can use with **dy/dx=cos(x)-sin(x)**. The extremas I found were a absolute max of 1 at f(0) and min of -1 at f(-1). I'm just curious if there's a better way to find the critical number.

Answer (score 0):

If $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ is to find the extrema then $\cos(x)-\sin(x)=0$, that is $1-\tan(x)=0$. This implies that $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, which is in the interval that you require.

Comment: >"that is 1-tan(x)=0"  I might have forgotten something but how did you get to this step?

Comment: divide $\cos x-\sin x=0$ with $\cos x$ and use $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \cos (x - \frac{\pi}{4})$$
The extrema of this function is located at $x = \frac{\pi}{4} \pm 2\pi n$ and $x = \frac{5\pi}{4} \pm 2\pi n$. In your case, $\frac{\pi}{4}$ would be the only extremum.